# Why does my HighStock data drop off when I zoom out?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a JsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hh3ocm4t/

In the initial view, the tooltip shows daily volume.

The tooltip formatter code is as follows:

```
    formatter: function() {
        var result = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + '</b>';


        for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
            var datum = this.points[i];
            console.log(datum);
            result += '<br />Original price: $' + datum.point.high.toFixed(2);
            result += '<br />Dropped price: $' + datum.point.low.toFixed(2);
                                result += '<br />Daily volume: ' + datum.point.name;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But when I click 'all' the daily volume becomes undefined.

How do I get my daily volume to appear when I click 'All'?

Comment: Everything works fine for me when I click on All - tested on Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default **data grouping** is enabled in Highstock. The solution here is disabling it:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Temperatures',
        data: data,
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/yu1ybnje/

**Docs reference:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping